# How to split a dataframe a list of dataframes (while dropping the grouped column)

Tags: r, dataframe

Similar questions have been asked, but I cannot figure out one last step.

How can I split a large data frame into a list of the data.frames and drop the column that grouped the rows into a specific dataframe?

Example:

```
#Load large dataframe
data <- mtcars

# split into a list based on "cyl" column
data_list <- split(data, f=data$cyl, drop = TRUE)
```

Then from here I want to remove "cyl" column from all of the dataframes in the list. Without going through each dataframe in the list, is there a way to remove this column?

Thanks!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

While we do the `split`, we can subset

```
data_list <- split(data[setdiff(names(data), 'cyl')], f=data$cyl, drop = TRUE)
```

Or if it is already created, then use

```
data_list <- lapply(data_list, subset, select = -cyl)
```

---

Or another option is `group_split` from `dplyr` and make use of `.keep` which is TRUE by default

```
library(dplyr)
data_list <- data %>% 
                 group_split(cyl, .keep = FALSE)
```